# Displaying and editing date in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have simple application which show table from sqlite database in QTableView. One column of table is for storing date. I want to provide user easy way to modify date in this column. I have reimplemented `data` method of `QtSql.QSqlTableModel` to change `QVariant` type to `QDate`:

```
class Model(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    [...]

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.column() == 3:
            return super(Model, self).data(index, role).toDate()
        return super(Model, self).data(index, role)

    [...]
```

After this change I got column:

[image: date column]

But user dont have possibility to have empty date. How can I fix that?

Is it possible to have calendar popup instead of this date edit? Should I use delegate or there is other way go? If delegate is best way, how to set delegate for single QTableView column?

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate to provide custom editor-widgets. `QTableView::setItemDelegateForColumn` method can help you [qdoc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegateForColumn)